# Unable to dockerize a nodeapp

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

**Created the docker file as following:**

```
FROM node:boron

ADD package.json package.json

RUN npm install
ADD . .

EXPOSE 4500

CMD ["node","main.js"]
```

**Building the app:**

docker build -t "appname"

**Running the app:**

docker run -it "appname"

**Inside `main.js`, I have:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require("request");

var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.set('port', (port));
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});

//app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public_html')))
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public_html'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '5mb',
    extended: false
}));


app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('public_html/');
});

//app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
//    res.sendFile('/index.html');
//});

app.use('*', function (req, res, err) {
//    console.log('error:  ', err);
});
```

when I run the app using docker command 'docker run -it "appname"`, I get the out to console:

`Node app is running on port 3001`

But when I browse, page is empty or nothing is loaded in the browser/output/view. It is supposed to pick up `index.html` from `response.render('public_html/');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly expose the port which your app is supposed to run on:

```
docker run -p 3001:3001 your-node-image
```

Then you can access your container's service on your docker host under http://localhost:3001, because `-p 3001:3001` binds the host port 3001 (the first 3001 in the argument) to the container's port 3001 (the second 3001).

`EXPOSE` from your Dockerfile only describes which ports are exposed by your application (which is in your Dockerfile 4500 and in your program port 3001...? Why are they different?). Publishing ports with `-p` is also necessary to access the container, [see the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime. EXPOSE does not make the ports of the container accessible to the host. To do that, you must use either the -p flag to publish a range of ports or the -P flag to publish all of the exposed ports.

Additionally, the flags `-it` appear to be useless with your service. You need these flags when you want to have an interactive session, e.g. when you're starting a shell in your container.

See here some more information about port exposal [in the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)

Comment: I am already exposing the port in docker file like: `EXPOSE 4500` so it doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, I extended the answer. You need to publish the ports with `-p` to make them accessible from your host

Comment: So I can do `docker run -p 3001:6000 your-node-image` and open my app on port 6000 ?

Comment: Wrong order: `docker run -p 6000:3001 your-node-image`. It's PORT_HOST:PORT_CONTAINER

Comment: I have one more quick question. I want to deploy app/docker image to cloud along with mongo database inside same image. So that I can deploy the complete image to cloud. How do I do that?

Comment: The philosophy behind docker is that you split your applications into small services and put each task in one of these images. Therefore, it is usual to define separate images for the database and for the core logic of your application. These services are typically connected with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) or similar.

Comment: Oh now I see the picture. Thank you